# Delete html tags in sed or similar

Tags: html, sed, tags

I am trying to fetch contents of table from a wepage. I jsut need the contents but not the tags `<tr></tr>`. I don't even need "tr" or "td" just the content. for eg:

```
<td> I want only this </td>
<tr> and also this </tr>
<TABLE> only texts/numbers in between tags and not the tags. </TABLE>
```

also I would like to put the first column output like this in a new csv file
column1,info1,info2,info3
coumn2,info1,info2,info3

I tried sed to deleted patters `<tr>` `<td>` but when I fetch table there are also other tags like `<color>` `<span>` etc. so I want is to delete all the tags; in short everything with < and > .

Comment: How regular is the content? You might be able to use [`lynx`](http://lynx.browser.org/) to grab the page and convert it to text and then parse the plain text. Hard to say without more specifics, screen scraping tends to be a choice between various ugly hacks.

Comment: ok this solved the first problem **sed -e 's/<.*>//g' input** . and to the comment above I wget'ed the pages and scraped only the table part. so file contains only clean table tags and datas. something like a exam time table routine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g'` will strip all tags out, but you might want to replace them with a space so tags that are next to each other don't run together: `<td>one</td><td>two</td>` becoming: `onetwo`.  So you could do `sed 's/<[^>]\+>/ /g'` so it would output `one two` (well, actually `one two`).

That said unless you need just the raw text, and it sounds like you are trying to do some transformations to the data after stripping the tags, a scripting language like Perl might be a more fitting tool to do this stuff with.

As mu is too short mentioned scraping HTML can be a bit dicey, using something that actually parses the HTML for you would be the best way to do this.  [PHPs DOM API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) is pretty good for these kinds of things.

Answer (score 2):

## Original:

Mac Terminal REGEX behaves a bit differently.  I was able to do this on my Mac using the following example:

```
$ curl google.com | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   219  100   219    0     0    385      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   385

301 Moved
301 Moved
The document has moved
here.

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

## Edit:

Just for clarification sake the origional looked like:

```
$ curl googl.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Also the annoying curl header can be rid of using the -s option:

```
$ curl -s google.com | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' 

301 Moved
301 Moved
The document has moved
here.

$
```

Answer (score 0):

This will delete specified tags:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

# based on: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/606006/37153

import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("2 args required: HTML/XML file, tag name")
    sys.exit(1)

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, features="lxml")
for s in soup(sys.argv[2]):       # https://gist.github.com/leonardreidy/40381da2588126928058
    s.extract()
print(soup)
```