# How to put a single column item into a single row?

Tags: python, c

I have a file like this:

```
a
b
c
d



e
f
g
h
```

and so on, with a single word/number on each line. and after 4/5 lines a couple of ( or three ) space. what I want to do is put them like this

```
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
```

I was working with sed, but sed is oneliner and seems to helpless for the addition of multiple lines. Can anybody help me with a shell script? I know this must be done easily via Perl, Python or at most C.

Comment: This is not a "please write my code for me" site. For that, you need to try something like [Rentacoder](http://www.rentacoder.com). Please show us what you've tried so far and explain how did it not work like you expected, and someone here will probably be glad to help you figure out why. You need to show that you've at least put some effort into trying it yourself first, though. Also, please read what you're writing before posting; I doubt very seriously you got one "answeer" yourself and "psoted" back, "ddi not get" an answer to your second question, and so forth.

Comment: @KenWhite: vWorker, not Rent-a-Coder. Don't ask how I know >.>

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: OK, I won't. :) Not familiar with vWorker; substitute "anywhere you can hire someone to write code for you because you're too lazy to figure it out for yourself" for Rentacoder if you prefer. <g>.

Comment: @KenWhite sorry that i did not explain what i worked on before on solving this problem and came back here. you can see my previous post here [link] ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593481/delete-html-tags-sed-or-similar ) which I found answer and commented my answer. even after getting one more answer i had accepted it. further i ll be putting on also what din't work and what i did. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done a wide variety of ways without anything even as complicated as sed, much less Perl or Python. My weapon of choice would be [tr](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_tr.htm):

```
cat inFile.txt | tr "\n" "," | tr ",,,," " " > outFile.txt
```