# How to remove the html tags using sed

Tags: sed

Input is:

```
<h1>This is heading 1</h1>
<h2>This is heading 2</h2>
<h3>This is heading 3</h3>
<h4>This is heading 4</h4>
<h5>This is heading 5</h5>
<h6>This is heading 6</h6>

</body>
</html>
```

Expected Ouput:

```
This is heading 1
This is heading 2
This is heading 3
This is heading 4
This is heading 5
This is heading 6
```

I tried `sed -n 's/<[^>].*>//gp' example.html`
but get nothing on screen, it seems the regular expression is not right

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593481/delete-html-tags-sed-or-similar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete html tags in sed or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593481/delete-html-tags-in-sed-or-similar)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
sed -n 's/<[^>]*>//gp' test.csv | sed '/^$/d'
```

You are almost there, the dot(.) you used could match a ">" character, so remove it from you command

the command after pipe is to clear all blank lines

Answer (score 0):

`grep` should be enough for this if your version supports `-P` option for PCRE.

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=>)(.[^<]+)(?=<)' file
This is heading 1
This is heading 2
This is heading 3
This is heading 4
This is heading 5
This is heading 6
```

Answer (score -1):

Work on your sample

```
sed -n 's|</\{0,1\}h[0-9]>||gp' YourFile
```

replace any  and  on line and if there is a modification, print the line

to be more exact (assuming tag

```
sed -n 's|^[[:space:]]*<\(h[0-9]>\)\(.*\)</\1|\2|p' YourFile
```