# Using sed to split up JSON

Tags: bash, sed

When using sed on code such as:

```
echo '{"id": 356709, "author": tom, "time": hello, "author2": {"id": 444444, "pain": high}}' | sed -n 's/^.*"id":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/p'
```

Why does it return only  444444 and not the first id, 356709.

All help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Don't use `sed`. Use a tool that actually knows about JSON, like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Comment: I want to do this without additional dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Assuming valid JSON, this is simply

```
json='{"id": 356709, "author": "tom", "time": "hello", "author2": {"id": 444444, "pain": "high"}}'
echo "$json" | jq '.id'
```

with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). Use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use a json parser for this job (see Chepner's answer).  If one really wants to use `sed` (or `awk`), see below.

#### Using sed

This produces the first ID:

```
$ cat File
{"id": 356709, "author": tom, "time": hello, "author2": {"id": 444444, "pain": high}}
$ sed -nE 's/"id": ([^,]*),.*$/\n\1/; s/[^\n]*\n//' File
356709
```

Because sed regular expressions are greedy, the first substitute command matches on the first `id`.  The second substitute command is necessary to remove what comes before the first `id`.

How it works:

- `s/"id": ([^,]*),.*$/\n\1/`

  This matches from the first occurrence of `"id:"` to the end of the line while saving the id number itself in group 1.  It replaces this portion of the line with a newline, `\n`, followed by the id number, `\1`.

  Since `sed` reads input line-by-line, a newly read-in sed pattern space will never contain a newline character.  Thus, we can be sure that the `\n` that we add to the line with this command will be the only newline in the pattern space.
- `s/[^\n]*\n//`

  This matches from the beginning of the line to the first newline and removes it all.

#### Using awk

To get the first id using awk (this probably requires GNU awk):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1{print $1; exit}' RS='"id": ' File
356709
```

To get all ids using awk:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1{print $1}' RS='"id": ' File
356709
444444
```

**How it works:** awk implicitly reads a file one *record* at a time.  By default, awk treats one line as a record.  For our purposes, we ask it to break records on each `id`.  This is done as follows:

- `-F,`

  This tells awk to use a comma as the field separator
- `NR>1{print $1}`

  This tells awk to print the first field in all records after the first.
- `RS='"id": '`

  This tells awk to break up records wherever it sees the string `"id":`.  This assures that the first field in any record after the first will be an `id` number.

Comment: The second substitute command in the sed seems to be removing everything before including the value of the id?

Comment: @JustinMa The second substitute command removes everything up to and including the first newline, `\n`.  The  first newline was placed before the `id` by the first substitute command.  That is why the second substitute command leaves the `id` unchanged.

Comment: @JustinMa I just added some text to the answer to explain the `sed` command in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `^.*"id":` swallows the first `"id": 356709`.
Remember `.` matches any character and with `*` it reads any character any number of times.

Clearly this is not the best approach here but I can't proceed further because I don't have any idea about the expected output.

I am tempted to share this answer regarding the [[ removal of html tags ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7593836/1620779) using sed.

Comment: Is there a way to make it stop after passing the first "id"?

Comment: @JustinMa : As others suggested it is better to go ahead with `jq`. :-) Good luck

Answer (score 0):

john1024's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37443683/1563960) is the best so far, but is very specific to your string. for example, it would fail if there happens not to be a newline after the first `{`. here is an answer that more generally extracts all ids stored as `"id":number` in a string, json or otherwise.

how: 1. remove all whitespace with `tr`, 2. find all `"id":number` with `grep`, 3. only output numbers with `grep`.

```
echo "$json" |
  tr -d ' \t\n\r\f' |
  grep -o '"id":[0-9]\+' |
  grep -o '[0-9]\+'
```

to only output the first id, add `-m1` to the last `grep`:

```
echo "$json" |
  tr -d ' \t\n\r\f' |
  grep -o '"id":[0-9]\+' |
  grep -m1 -o '[0-9]\+'
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to only have the first ID shown though?

Answer (score 0):

When you think you can trust the layout in your example, you can try:

```
echo '{"id": 356709, "author": tom, "time": hello, "author2": {"id": 444444, "pain": high}}' |
   sed 's/[^,]*id": \([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

or

```
echo '{"id": 356709, "author": tom, "time": hello, "author2": {"id": 444444, "pain": high}}' |
   tr "," "\n" | grep -Pom 1 "id.. \K\d*"
```