# Remove a html tag from text file in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

how can I remove all `"<br />"` from a txt file.
I tried it with

```
sed -i 's/<br>/\n/g' test.txt > test.txt
```

But it isn't working

Comment: You want to replace `<br />` but you're searching for the string `<br>`. Also, the way that command is written will clobber test.txt (i.e. overwrite its contents) before `sed` can read it; you can't read and write a file with shell redirection in the same pipeline. You either need to 1. use `sed -i` as @Leslie suggests, 2. write to a different file than you're reading, or 3. use a utility like [`sponge`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: [Delete html tags in sed or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7593836/608639), [Sed remove tags from html file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19878056/608639), [How to remove all HTML tags with sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307100/56041), etc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to delete both "<b>" and "</b>" and append "\n" to the block of text that was surrounded by the pair, you probably should just delete all the former and replace only the latter with "\n".  This sed command should do that:

```
sed -i -e 's|<b>||g' -e 's|</b>|\n|g' test.txt
```

I don't think you need the final output redirection if you use the "-i" parameter.