# Breakdown of sed command line that deletes all html tags

Tags: html, sed, tags

I have looked up methods for deleting html tags using sed. I came upon this thread:

[Delete html tags in sed or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593481/delete-html-tags-in-sed-or-similar)

User "Useless Code" suggested following line:

```
sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g'
```

As I'm a newbie to Stack Overflow and hence not yet allowed to comment on answers, I'm creating this thread to ask you for a breakdown of the command line above. 
I know what the "s" and the "g" do in the code, but that middle part, the `<[^>]\+>` specifically, confuse me quite a bit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's "`<` followed by one or more characters other than `>`, followed by `>`". The `+` quantifier is escaped; this is a GNU extension to basic regular expressions, which don't have a `+` quantifier, only extended regular expressions have it. GNU BRE allows `\+` to express the same thing.

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/sYY1YM/2) breaks it down; I replaced `\+` by `+` because regex101 doesn't support the GNU BRE flavour.

Comment: Please note that since `sed` works line-by-line, if an HTML tag is broken across multiple lines this won't work. Parsing or otherwise processing HTML with regex can at best work in only very limited circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[xyz]` means any character x, y, or z.
`[^xyz]` is the opposite, i.e. any character *other* than x, y, or z.
So `[^>]` means any character other than `>`.

Anything within a regular expression followed by a `+` means "one or more of these". So `[^>]+` means one or more characters that are not `>`.

Finally, `<[^>]+>` means `<` followed by one or more characters that are not `>`, followed by `>`. So basically `<anything>`.

All this is placed between `/` characters to mark the beginning and end of the regular expression's search pattern. The part between the 2nd and 3rd `/` is what any found matches are to be replaced with. Which is an empty string in this case because you just want to delete the tags.

The backslash before the `+` is because `sed` by default uses a limited version of regular expressions, you can also overcome this by using `sed -E`.

So `sed -E 's/<[^>]+>//g'` (note the absence of the backslash) would also work.

Note: you may wonder if `<>` would have to be removed as well. Strictly this is not a valid HTML tag but if it appears anyway, you'll probably want to get rid of that too. So instead of `+` you can use `*` which means zero or more of the preceding characters (instead of `+` which means one or more).